# CheckBoxPreference only returns default value

Tags: android, android-fragments, sharedpreferences, android-preferences

So for my app, I'm trying to allow users to change the default speed of a robot. To do this I use a `CheckBoxPreference`
This is my `preferences.xml`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <PreferenceCategory
            android:title="@string/prefsect_polling"
            android:summary="@string/prefsect_pollingSummary">



            <CheckBoxPreference
                android:key="batteryCheckBox"
                android:title="@string/pref_battery"
                android:summary="@string/pref_batterySummary"
                android:defaultValue="false" />

            <ListPreference
                android:key="timeIntervalListPref"
                android:title="@string/pref_interval"
                android:summary="@string/pref_intervalSummary"
                android:entries="@array/timeIntervalArray"
                android:entryValues="@array/timeIntervalArrayValues"/>

        </PreferenceCategory>

        <PreferenceCategory
            android:title="@string/prefsect_servo"
            android:summary="@string/prefsect_servoSummary">

            <CheckBoxPreference
                android:key="speedCheckbox"
                android:title="@string/pref_speed"
                android:summary="@string/pref_speedSummary"
                android:defaultValue="false" />

        </PreferenceCategory>

    </PreferenceScreen>
```

When I go to load my preferences into one of my Fragments in my ViewPager, I use this line of code
`SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity().getBaseContext());`

To begin my `PreferencesActivity`, I use this intent which is triggered by an menu item press

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,EditPreferences.class);
    startActivity(intent);
```

I setup my EditPrefences Activity like this

```
    public class EditPreferences extends PreferenceActivity{

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new MyPreferenceFragment()).commit();
            PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this,R.xml.preferences,false);
        }

        public static class MyPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment{
            @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

When trying to read my `CheckBoxPreference` I use an `OnResume` method which is contained inside a `Fragment`

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity().getBaseContext());
    boolean defaultSpeed = pref.getBoolean("speedCheckBox",false);
    if(defaultSpeed){
        powerControl.setProgress(100);
    }
    else{
        powerControl.setProgress(75);
    }
}
```

My Problem is occurring when I go to read my Preferences for my App. They save and read correctly in my app. I can open my preferences activity and it shows the previous value. When I call `boolean speedDefault = pref.getBoolean("speedCheckBox",false);` It only returns the default value. When I go into the debugger and I look at mMap, it shows speedCheckBox's correct value, but for some reason I cannot figure out why it isn't reading the correct value.

Edit: I opted for using an `EditTextPreference` instead since it would allow more freedom to the user, but I want to leave this question open since someone else might come across an issue like this given someone can help figure this out. To access the preferences for `EditTextPreference` and `ListPreference` I used `pref.getString("PreferenceName","defaultStringValue");` and this returns the correct results for those preferences. Still not sure why `getBoolean` doesn't return the correct value for `CheckBoxPreference` since it will only ever have 2 states, true or false.